# Firebase with clusters

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, node-cluster

I am using Node.js with Firebase. I want to use all the cpu-cores, by using cluster-module.
Do these two work together? As I have binded firebase nodes with event listeners and Firebase maintains socket between NodeJs and firebase.
How can I use all CPUs of an instance (GAE).

Comment: Assuming you are using firebase as dbs for backend, use command `pm2 start app.js -i max` to use app cpu

Comment: yes, I am using firebase as DB and hosted the app on Google cloud. pm2 seems nice, I will definitely check it.

Comment: pm2 start app.js -i max this is fine, but I want to initiate only one firebase listener, not multiple. the above command will create x instances and x listener, equal to the numbers of core.